# how to programme an eye tracking based computer mouse in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, mouse, eye-tracking

I am doing a project where I have to develop an application in which the mouse cursor moves according to the co-ordinates provided to it.These co-ordinates are generated from the position of user's pupil.I am able to get the co-ordinates of the pupil using opencv.Now,I have the following questions:

1.)How do I programme the mouse cursor,so that it moves according to the co-ordinates I give it.Specifically,I am looking for libraries and functions that will do it.After looking online I found out that people use **graphics.h** library with turbo C.I am doing my project in visual studio 2010,so please let me know of any method that goes with it.

2.)Secondly,how can I use this so-called mouse I have created with C++ and opencv to function as the primary mouse in windows?Do I have to do assembly level programming or device driver writing or is there any other suitable method?

For Q1. I would highly appreciate if you could give me some sample code.

Thanks.

............................
This is what I have done so far
..............................
I am having problems with running code.I have integrated WinBGIm v6.0 from http://winbgim.codecutter.org/
(I am using VS2010 ultimate on Windows 7). If I run the sample code everything goes fine.However, when I tried to run this mouse example given in the documentation several errors occurred.
Please help me correct the errors, I have no idea what they mean.

```
/* mouse example */
/*Filename:mint.cpp*/
    #include "winbgim.h"
    void main(void)
    {
    const int LIMIT = 10; // Number of clicks to stop program.
    int maxx, maxy; // Maximum x and y pixel coordinates
    int count = 0; // Number of mouse clicks
    int divisor; // Divisor for the length of a triangle side
    // Put the machine into graphics mode and get the maximum
    coordinates:
    initwindow(450, 300);
    maxx = getmaxx( );
    maxy = getmaxy( );
    // Draw a white circle with red inside and a radius of 50 pixels:
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, RED);
    setcolor(WHITE);
    fillellipse(maxx/2, maxy/2, 50, 50);
    // Print a message and wait for a red pixel to be double clicked:
    settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
    outtextxy(20, 20, "Left click " << LIMIT << " times to end.");
    setcolor(BLUE);
    divisor = 2;
    while (count < LIMIT)
    {
    triangle(maxx/divisor, maxy/divisor);
    delay(500);
    divisor++;
    if (ismouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN))
    {
    (clearmouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN));
    count++;
    }
    }
    // Switch back to text mode:
    closegraph( );
    }
...................................................
The compiler errors are:

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\winbgim.h(302): error C2086: 'int right' : redefinition
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\winbgim.h(302) : see declaration of 'right'
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\winbgm\driver\mint.cpp(20): error C2296: '<<' : illegal, left operand has type 'const char [12]'
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\winbgm\driver\mint.cpp(25): error C3861: 'triangle': identifier not found
Build FAILED.
```

Comment: You don't have to built an actual mouse driver, you can just move the OS pointer from your C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use a port of BGI library for Windows (WinBGIm). Here's a link to a general idea of how to do it (sample project in VS2010).
   Project: http://muhammadallee.pbworks.com/w/file/53399106/WinBGIm-Demo.zip
   (You would need to go to Project Properties->Linker->Input and correct the path of the lib file there.
   Alternatively, use this project:
   http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/visual/BGI2010.zip
   Documentation:
   http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/
2. It will use the Windows standard mouse. So you don't have to worry about it. You can simply set the coordinates of the mouse via `SetMousePos()` that you are using the set the coordinates of your own mouse.

Your code contains errors

Instead of

```
outtextxy(20, 20, "Left click " LIMIT << " times to end.");
```

Use this code

```
char msg[80] = "";
sprintf(msg, "Left click %d times to end.", LIMIT);
```

And comment out

```
triangle(maxx/divisor, maxy/divisor);
```

Also, download from the links that I have mentioned. After these changes, it ran fine.

PS: If it solves your problem, you can mark this as answer :)

Comment: Well,I get the following errors when I try to run the mouse example given in the documentation.I don't have any idea what they mean.

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\winbgim.h(302): error C2086: 'int right' : redefinition
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\winbgim.h(302) : see declaration of 'right'
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\winbgm\driver\mint.cpp(20): error C2296: '<<' : illegal, left operand has type 'const char [12]'
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\winbgm\driver\mint.cpp(25): error C3861: 'triangle': identifier not found
Build FAILED.

Comment: please see the question,i have given the details there.Thanks!!

Comment: @HassanJaved I have updated my answer against your updated question.